# VueJS firebase interaction Promises

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, vue.js, promise, vuefire

I've a Firebase db who
looks like this.

[image]

I've got a lots of product with different IDs.

Now : I've a function getbyID in my API :

```
  getbyId: function(myId) {
          var obj = FireBase.database().ref('product')
          .orderByChild('id')
          .equalTo(myId)
          .once("value", function(snapshot) {
              var key;
              snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                  key = childSnapshot.key;
                  return true;
              });
              if (key) {
                  console.log(FireBase.database().ref('product').child(key).toString());
                  return (FireBase.database().ref('product').child(key).toString());
              } else {
                  console.log("Your ID doesn't exist");
              }
          });
      console.log(obj);
      return (obj);
  },
```

I want this function to return the JSON corresponding to the child with the good ID I gave in param.
It's working when I print with console log after the if (key)

```
          console.log(FireBase.database().ref('product').child(key).toString());
```

This console.log print me the link of the elem(and not the Json :()

However the problem is when I print "obj"

```
console.log(obj)
```

this console.log print me the promise :(( So I cannot return the elemement I want. I can't find why.

I heard about async and wait, but I don't know how to implement it.

Thank you really much

Comment: Yes, you cannot return the element, you only can return a promise for it. That's fine. Just consume the result using `.then()` or `await` where you call the method.

Comment: Thank you really much :) It's seems logical !